# Error when executing SQLAgent job in SQL 2012 which starts ssis package built in 2008

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sql-agent-job

I've built a SSIS package in 2008 R2. It works perfectly so now I want to install it on a server of a customer. Though they have installed SQL Server 2012.
After converting the package i've executed it within the solution succesfully.
Though if I try to run a SQL Server Agent Job designed to execute the package it gives the following error:

> To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must
>   install Read Ini of Integration Services or higher.

(Read Ini is the first task the package should execute.)

I've checked and Integration Services 11.0 is installed. Also the SQL Server Agent user has been granted permissions to the Integration Services.

The package has been built under Integration Services 10.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration Services is a little touchy.
you can execute, becouse when you lanch the package, it runs on your machine.

i suggest to recreate the package on SSIS 2012.